# Recursive function (bracket sequence)

Tags: python, recursion

This not my decision but I want to know how it work's. Put `print` into function. Task: Find all correct bracket sequence where length is `2 ⋅ n`. Only round brackets.

```
def foo(search, left, right, pairs):
    if left == pairs and right == pairs:
        print(search)
    else:
        print(left, right, 'else',)
        if left < pairs:
            print(left, right,'left')
            foo(search + '(', left + 1, right, pairs)
        if right < left:
            print(left, right, 'right')
            foo(search + ')', left, right + 1, pairs)

foo('', 0, 0, 3)
```

Until the first correct sequence generation all clear. But next there are some questions. There are `prints` from first to second correct generation:

```
((()))
2 0 right
2 1 else
2 1 left
3 1 else
3 1 right
3 2 else
3 2 right
(()())
```

Why in first `print` after first correct sequence `left, right = 2, 0`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your question is?

Comment: @AMC I'm interested about how after `print(search)` in the next iteration left and right variables become to 2 and 0?

Comment: Right, I got that part, I was asking if you can be more specific. Which part of the process are you stuck at? Where is the issue?

Comment: @AMC I mean, how after right and left variables both were equal to three and I get first correct sequence and in next iteration there are 2 and 0?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `left` and `right` start off at 0, and `pairs` is 3. `2 0 right` as the result of the first `print()` statement seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the recursion stack unwinding. Every time you call foo from first if loop

```
if left < pairs:
```

The second if loop of (right < left:)  is stacked and will be called when foo returns from if left < pairs call.

One way to see the stacks is modify the first loop condition like this:

```
    if left < pairs:
        print(left, right,'left')
        print ("stacked -", ( left, right, 'right'))
        foo(search + '(', left + 1, right, pairs)
        # next if loop will be called once this foo returns
    if right < left:
        print(left, right, 'right')
        foo(search + ')', left, right + 1, pairs)
```

It will print the value of left, right for which it still has to go through the next if case but waiting for returning from foo call from first if loop. I understand its a bit confusing but you can put more print statements to see how it works.

e.g sample output:

```
(0, 0, 'else')
(0, 0, 'left')
('stacked -', (0, 0, 'right'))
(1, 0, 'else')
(1, 0, 'left')
('stacked -', (1, 0, 'right'))
(2, 0, 'else')
(2, 0, 'left')
('stacked -', (2, 0, 'right'))
(3, 0, 'else')
(3, 0, 'right')
(3, 1, 'else')
(3, 1, 'right')
(3, 2, 'else')
(3, 2, 'right')
((()))
(2, 0, 'right')
```

Now if you see in this output last stacked was for  ('stacked -', (2, 0, 'right')) so when it unwinds it will be executed first.